# $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: analysis, limits

What is the negation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty.$

I have written this $ \forall\ M\in \ \mathbb{R}^+\ |x|\geq M \implies |f(x)| \ge M. $

Answer (score 2):

The statement:
$$
\forall M \in\mathbb{R_+}\ \exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\ \forall x\geq x_0\ f(x) \geq M
$$
(which corresponds to the statement "for every value $M$, for any $x$  sufficiently big $f(x)$ stays above $M$).
Can you figure its negation using the "usual rules"?

> $$\exists M \in\mathbb{R_+}\ \forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\ \exists x\geq x_0\ f(x) < M$$